# Subgroups contained in the set of normal matrices

Tags: matrices, group-theory

Let $N \subset \mathbb{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ be the set of normal invertible matrices acting on $\mathbb{C}^n$. The set $N$ is closed under inverses but are not closed under multiplication, hence is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$.

This has made we wonder, what are some examples of subgroups of $\mathbb{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ which are contained in $N$? An obvious example is the group of unitary matrices. Are there any other interesting examples of such subgroups? Surprisingly, a search on the internet was not able to yield any examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All powers, positive and negative, of an invertible normal matrix are invertible and normal, so the powers of an invertible normal matrix form a subgroup. If $A$ is normal and invertible, then the set of all matrices of the form $cA^n$, $c$ a nonzero scalar, $n$ an integer, form a subgroup.
You might also find something of interest in Laffey, T. J. “Finite Groups Generated by a Pair of Unitary Matrices with Normal Sum.” Proceedings of the Royal Irish Academy. Section A: Mathematical and Physical Sciences 77 (1977): 61–74. http://www.jstor.org/stable/20489066.